# Best wireless card (USB or PCI) that works with Windows XP x64?

Tags: wireless-networking

Currently i'm using a Belkin Wireless-G card in my main pc to connect to the router downstairs, but it's a bit erratic, taking a while to connect and sometimes not connecting at all. The router is an ordinary Netgear one, again just 'regular G'. I only got the Belkin one working by finding that the card manufacturer Ralink made their own 64-bit drivers - Belkin don't for x64. But i'm hoping there's something out there with a bit more quality that works with x64 XP. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot of it is down to the antenna, so it would be worth making sure you get something that can use a detachable antenna, if your current card has the option of adding an antenna then you might want to try that first.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, although the antenna is indeed detachable.

Comment: It's worked for me although I've only used it with PCI cards I don't see why it wouldn't help with USB as well.

Answer (score 1):

My choice: **Linksys Wireless-N PCI Adapter WMP300N**

[image]

Works with Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: A great adapter, +1.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this card

[Super G 802.11BG Wireless Pci 64 Bit Xp Compliant Turbo Mode](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000M5U9GI)

I use it with my xp 64 bit and its fast too

Comment: Interesting, but i can't seem to find much of that brand in the UK.

Comment: Found a uk link :)
Do you have a matching MSI router, or is it fine anyway?

Comment: Its fine, trust me

Answer (score 0):

The [D-Link DWA-547](http://www.dlink.co.uk/cs/Satellite?c=Product_C&childpagename=DLinkEurope-GB%2FDLProductCarousel&cid=1197319489522&p=1197318962342&packedargs=ParentPageID%3D1197318962321%26TopLevelPageProduct%3DConsumer%26locale%3D1195806691854%26packedargs%3DProductParentID%253D1195808623928&pagename=DLinkEurope-GB%2FDLWrapper) is just perfect. You can use it on Windows x64 using the Atheros drivers. In fact, it is usable in pretty much every OS, with near-perfect support for Linux. Moreover, it supports 802.11n.

I bought 3 of those for my family's computers. One is running Windows XP x64, one is running Windows 7 Pro x86, and the other is using the card in master mode to create an access point on Linux Debian using hostapd (yes, it can do that, too).

As far as I can tell, this card is just perfect. A little expensive though, but it's worth the price.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't think brand matters to much. I wouldn't worry about the card to much - for under £20, I see many similar designs using the same realtek reference design.

I recommend that you just look into buying yourself a new antenna such as what they sell from [Hawking Technology](http://www.hawkingtech.com/).

As you said PCI, I am guessing desktop and you do not take this around with you much. If you are willing to spend money on a new antenna / card, you may just want to go into another direction and look at [homeplug](http://www.homeplug.org/home) based networking. I have had good experiences with it and you can easily get 200Mb+ (on a GB ethernet socket).